# CSV match cell value to Current time

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV with data as

```
Date        Time        Impact  Warning
12/20/2021  10:00 AM    Low     9:57:00 AM
12/21/2021  8:30 AM     Low     8:27:00 AM
12/22/2021  8:30 AM     Medium  8:27:00 AM
```

I have a timer loop running and I want the variable- $eventsoon to be true if a Warning time is -eq to Current time(EST).

```
#Import CSV
$csv = Import-Csv C:\filelocation.csv

#Get eastern Timezone#
$eastern = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::convertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId([datetime]::Now, 'Eastern Standard Time')
#Format Eastern Time#
$easternTime = Get-Date $eastern -format "HH:mm:ss tt"

#Find Matching Time between Current US Eastern Time and Warningtime
 $eventsoon = $csv  |
    Where-Object { $_.Warning -eq  $easternTime} |
    ForEach-Object {
      
        Write-Host ($_.Warning,$_.Impact) 
    }
 $eventsoon
```

When testing, I can trigger the -eq but nothing saves to the $eventsoon variable?

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Output from `Write-Host` is not captured unless redirected ( `6>&1` ). Don't use it :)

Comment: I was using write-host for testing.. I'll keep working on it. Thank you Santiago

Comment: have you looked at what is in `$EasternTime`? you used `HH:mm:ss tt` ... and that will give `08:27:00 AM` ... but your `$_.Warning` will show `8:27:00 AM`. [*grin*] ///// **_that is one reason why you should NOT compare datetime strings - instead compare date time objects._***

Comment: correct, im trying to -eq a string and an object.  Trying to get the string to an object

Comment: @MattyS - so convert your `$_.Warning` to a datetime object AND leave your `$EasternTime` as a datetime object instead of forcing it into a date string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint on how you can approach your problem, first of all, [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426172/csv-match-cell-value-to-current-time#comment124492547_70426172) has given you a great peace of advice: *always use [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) to compare Dates and Times*.
Another thing to note, using `-eq` might not be the right comparison operator, specially to filter **Time**, normally you would filter by time ranges, something like: *"2 minutes more than this and 2 mintues less than this..."*

Here goes the hint:

```
$csv = @'
Date        Time        Impact  Warning
12/20/2021  10:00 AM    Low     9:57:00 AM
12/21/2021  8:30 AM     Low     8:27:00 AM
12/22/2021  8:30 AM     Medium  8:27:00 AM
12/22/2021  8:30 AM     Medium  1:50:00 PM
'@ -replace '  +',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Let's try to filter the last line of the CSV (1:50:00 PM)

$est = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
    [datetime]::Now,
    'Eastern Standard Time'
) # => Monday, December 20, 2021 1:48:45 PM

$result = $csv | Where-Object {
    [datetime]$_.Warning -gt $est.AddMinutes(-15) -and
    [datetime]$_.Warning -lt $est.AddMinutes(15)
}

# $result would yield:

Date       Time    Impact Warning
----       ----    ------ -------
12/22/2021 8:30 AM Medium 1:50:00 PM

# If you want to see just a True / False
[bool]$result # => True
```

Comment: Thank you for all your helps today.  Really cleared up my uncertanties.

Comment: @MattyS happy to help and glad you're learning something new :)